# ShowDialog in WPF throwing not agree with the current state

Tags: c#, wpf

I keep getting the following error when i open a `SaveFileDialog` in WPF, but i must be honest and say that the error dose not make much sense to me.

Information for developers:

> This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox Items.Count:4' with name '(unnamed)' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:
>     Accumulated count 2 is different from actual count 4.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]
>
> One or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:
>        System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator
>         System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
>          System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView
>     *     XmlDiff.Gui.ViewModels.MTObservableCollection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   (The starred sources are considered more likely to be the cause of the problem.)
>
> The most common causes are (a) changing the collection or its Count without raising a corresponding event, and (b) raising an event with an incorrect index or item parameter.
>
> The exception's stack trace describes how the inconsistencies were detected, not how they occurred.  To get a more timely exception, set the attached property 'PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel' on the generator to value 'High' and rerun the scenario.  One way to do this is to run a command similar to the following:
>      System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator, System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High)
>   from the Immediate window.  This causes the detection logic to run after every CollectionChanged event, so it will slow down the application.

The error occur when i run the following method. It dose not run on the GUI thread, but should that matter when i create a new SaveFileDialog.

```
private string ShowSaveFileDialog(string defaultName)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog
    {
        FileName = defaultName,
        DefaultExt = ".xml",
        Filter = "Xml documents (.xml)|*.xml"
    };

    // Show open file dialog box 
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Process open file dialog box results 
    if (result == true)
        return dlg.FileName;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does it work on the main GUI thread?

Comment: No `It dose not run on the GUI thread, but should that matter when i create a new SaveFileDialog.`

Comment: I meant: _"Would it run if you call it on the main GUI thread?"_

Comment: It is only some times it dose this! 80% of the time dose it run without any prolems

Comment: *No It dose not run on the GUI thread, but should that matter when i create a new SaveFileDialog*... Yes, that *does* matter. UI objects should run on the UI thread.

Comment: It does sound like a threading / sync issue. Have a look at locking the collection to synchronise access - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have some code that is adding files into the folder on another thread. You should look at locking the collection before accessing it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

```
lock (mycollection){
    //modify the collection in a threadsafe manner
}
```